# Reading multiple lines from the queue in service broker in SQL server

Tags: service-broker

I am using the following command to read from the queue. But it returns only one row. I noticed that conversation_handle is unique for all messages. How can I read top 100 or all the rows from the queue in sql server?

RECEIVE *-- @handle=conversation_handle, --@xml=CAST(message_body AS XML) FROM EventData_Destination_Queue

Answer (score 1):

as [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963) says:

> WHERE
>       Specifies the conversation or conversation group for the received messages. If omitted, returns messages from the next available
>   conversation group.

That mean- if next conversation group contains 1 message, it returns just 1 message. So maybe what you want is to group messages in one conversation group at the time of sending them.

Comment: Janis- I can not group the messages in one group while sending to the queue. Can you tell me the way to read multiple messages from the queue in this case

Comment: @user1646814 Why you cant? One of the approaches could be- make new conversation group, when sending messages use conversation group id to group messages. you can save that conversation group id in some state table. in microsoft connect you can find examples how to do that..